# Convert a number to its digits in C

Tags: c

This exercise asks to check if a number is equal to the sum of the cubes of its digits`

```
Example : 153 = 1+125+27= 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3
```

But When I make 153 the outpout is 152 ,Can you help me

```
    bool Number(double n)
    {
        double k=n , m , s=0 ;
        while(k!=0)
        {   
            m=k %10 ;
            s=s+pow(m,3) ;
            k=(k-m)/10 ;
        }
       if(s==n)
       {
            return true ;
       }
       else
       {
            return false ;
       }
    }
    int main()
    {
        double n ;
        printf("give n please : ") ;
        scanf("%f", &n) ;
        if(Number(n)==true)
        {
              printf("\nThe sum of the cubes of its digits is equal to itself !\n") ;
        }
        else
        {
              printf("\nThe sum of the cubes of its digits is not equal to itself !\n") ;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: you should not need to use `double` or `pow()` for integer arithmetic. Anyway `%` is illegal for `double` operands.

Comment: What is your question? Is it not working? What input are you using? What output do you expect?

Comment: Yes ,is not worked ,when i make 153 the result is 152

Comment: That's indicative of a typical rounding error from using `pow()` and `double`. You can cube a single digit with say `int n = 9; int cube = n * n * n;` without risk of overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        k=(k-m)/10 ;
```

With above, `k` might bypass `0` and become negative.

```
while(k!=0)
{   
    m=k %10 ;
    s=s+pow(m,3) ;
    k=(k-m)/10 ;
}
```

you just need

```
    while(k!=0)
    {   
        m=k %10 ;
        s=s+pow(m,3) ;
        k=k/10 ;
    }
```